# Bash exclude a line from ouput if the line matches a certain text

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am looking to create a cronjob that will alert us if a certain directory has sent out a certain amount of emails from scanning a log file.  The one liner I am using is:

```
awk '$3 ~ /^cwd/{print $3}' /var/log/exim_mainlog | sort | uniq -c | sed "s|^ *||g" | sort -nr | head --lines 5
```

before I get any further, I need to exclude some locations from the output, example:

```
50992 cwd=/var/spool/exim
21960 cwd=/home/USER1/public_html/wp-content/cache/object/000000/746
2717 cwd=/etc/csf
2063 cwd=/home/USER2
1072 cwd=/
```

I need to exclude:

```
1072 cwd=/
2717 cwd=/etc/csf
50992 cwd=/var/spool/exim
```

Would I need to append the output to a txt file then use SED or is there an easier method?

Comment: `... | grep -v 'thing_to_exclude'`

Comment: ...in this case, that might be `egrep -v ' cwd=(/$|/etc/csf|/var/spool/exim)'`.

Comment: Also, `sed` is actually a **stream** editor, not a file editor -- if you're using it to edit files on disk rather than streams, you're presumably using nonstandard extensions such as `-i`; the POSIX-standard **file** editor is `ex`, not `sed`.

Comment: Also, you could do all this inside of awk if you wanted to, instead of piping through a ton of other tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy egrep -v ' cwd=(/$|/etc/csf|/var/spool/exim)' That worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe through `grep -v` to exclude matches:

```
egrep -v ' cwd=(/$|/etc/csf|/var/spool/exim)'
```